# Parent zone does not provide glue for nameservers

Tags: domain-name-system

We have two domains:

1. gignouser.com
2. clouds.host

we have created two A records:

- ns1.eu.clouds.host
- ns2.eu.clouds.host

Both of these servers host the DNS for both domains, and are listed a nameservers on the domain.

Through our registrar, we have created two host entries for the two DNS servers and pointed them towards their real IP addresses.

The issue we are facing is that when running a report on `gignouser.com` we are getting the following error:

```
Parent zone does not provide glue for nameservers
```

I don't understand why this is happening as we have created all the normal DNS entries. My guess is that it is because the name servers are 1 level down, under .eu and that is where the DNS report is looking for the glue records. This seems odd however as I can't create those records without delegating the domain, and its all run on same DNS server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The parent zone is not obligated to provide glue records for a delegation if the delegated-to host names is not under the delegated name. Glue records are only needed if a delegation points to something that the delegation would need to be followed for to be useful.

Since you are delegating `gignouser.com` to name servers under `eu.clouds.host`, that is not the case and glue records are thus not required to be returned by the name servers hosting the delegation to `gignouser.com` -- meaning the `com` TLD DNS servers.

If you look at the delegation of `clouds.host` you will see that the delegation from the `nic.host` DNS servers does include glue records.

I do however notice something that may contribute to problems:

**You are serving NS RRs with a 0 TTL,** for both domains. This can be problematic. If you want to minimize the time that DNS servers cache the delegation data (why you'd want to do that to such an extent I don't know), then serve it with some small but non-zero TTL. I suggest using a minimum of 10 seconds TTL to give resolvers and proxies a chance to do their thing even if they abide by TTLs internally during the recursive resolution process.

I would fix the TTLs first, and see if the problem goes away. It's certainly possible that the report tool you are using is being confused by the zero TTLs.

I also notice that it appears that you are running both name servers on the same subnet -- specifically, on adjacent IP addresses -- which presents a massive single point of failure. If that is the case, *strongly* consider getting an off-site slave DNS server, *especially* if you want to serve zone authority data with very short TTLs. While "everything else will be down anyway" is a valid point on the face of it, *which error would you rather the users get if your servers are unavailable;* "the host name www.gignouser.com was not found" or "the server did not respond"? I would absolutely prefer the latter, even if the end result *at that moment* is the same in that your web site is unavailable.

Comment: thanks for the response, and the tip regarding the 0 TTL.. seems to be a bug in the Microsoft DNS Manager! .. anyway have updated. Also aware of servers on same subnet, if that location goes offline, then everything is down anyway!

Answer (score -1):

Have you created NS entries in the domain configuration file ? Like that :

```
gignouser.com.        IN      NS      ns1.eu.clouds.host.
gignouser.com.        IN      NS      ns2.eu.clouds.host.
```